# 2000s (or earlier) cyberpunk novel: dystopia, mega storm, omnipresent noise

Tags: story-identification, novel

I think there was more than one plot line.

One of these was about a group of people inside some bunker. They waited for a mega storm, which creates electronic interference or noise, then these people can take of explosive collars from their necks without activation.

Probably, on other plot line, there was some kind of omnipresent noise, that everyone can hear if they listened patiently.

It is not *Falling Out of Cars* by Jeff Noon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [*Heavy Weather*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1802) (1994) by Bruce Sterling.

[image: Cover of first printing]

The people in the bunker are a group of covert operatives employed by covert extra-governmental organizations.  They have been used to arrange operations,  assassinations, even the outbreak of plagues, in the name of keeping the world running, but now they want out.  Leo has been following the research of his brother Jerry - a storm-chaser - into the possibility of an "F-6" tornado.  The operatives have realized that the zone of silence - caused by massive damage to communications infrastructure in the wake of an F-6 tornado - will give them a few minutes free of surveillance.  They all wear radio-controlled explosive devices - disguised as heavy watches (not collars) - to keep them under the thumb of their masters.  Once the twister has passed, they take turns cutting the devices off one another.  (In at least 1 case they fail, killing both the person wearing the device and the person removing it; of the 8 operatives 6 make it out alive.)

The other thread concerns Alex, Juanita's brother, who has some kind of lung disease.  He's at an illegal clinic in Mexico where the doctor fills his lungs with an oxygenated fluid that's supposed to clear them out.  (The doctor calls it a "lung enema.")  Leo helps Juanita - Jerry's girlfriend - find him, and she rescues him from there to bring him back to the states.

They all meet up at the F-6; Juanita's driving an advanced vehicle - a "Storm Pursuit Vehicle" named "Charlie" that has "wheels" consisting of thousands of little pads on smart pistons, that can roll evenly over any terrain and even up stairs - but even it can't cope with the tornado.  Once it gets knocked out by damage caused by the storm, Leo has to rescue her, which is how she witnesses the operatives removing their control devices.

The omnipresent noise may be the sound of the F-6 which is so loud that at several kilometres distance it overwhelms everything else, even through noise-cancelling headphones.

There are some more details available in some of the [reviews on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/359386.Heavy_Weather).

Comment: Yes! That's It. I remember now the lung disease, and a treatment with liquid in the lungs. That's definitely it.

Comment: I didn't manage to finish this one. But I remember the presence of fully antibiotic-resistent strep/staph infections, and the car made of a fully transparent hull (of diamond?).

Comment: And it has 4 stars on goodreads... I don’t really know what to make of that given this summary of the plot...

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba Please don't go by this summary.  This totally concentrates on the details necessary to answer the question; there's a lot more that goes on, and the book is definitely one I'd recommend.